# Prove an intermediate subset equals one of the groups it lies between

Tags: group-theory

Let $R^*$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers. Given that $H \leq R^*$ and $R^+ \subseteq H \subseteq R^*$, prove $H = R^+$ or $H = R^*$.

My issue is my professor went over this example in class, but I came in late in to class to only hear that his solution which claimed that $H = R^*$ but I don't understand how that is possible.

For this to be true, $H$ must obviously contain the negative real numbers, in turn meaning $-1 \in H$ because every negative real number is the product of $-1$ and some $x \in R^+$, problem is, I have no idea how to prove that $-1 \in H$ or even $-1 \notin H$. I have been trying everything, and I cannot come up with anything conclusive for either, I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here.

I thought about perhaps assuming for contradiction that $-1 \notin H$ and then saying that $(-1)(-1) \notin H$ but $(-1)(-1) = 1 \in H$ giving us a contradiction to prove $-1 \in H$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $H \ne R^+$. Then since $H \subseteq R^*$, there must be some negative number $x \in H$. Then it must contain any negative number $y$, for $y = x \frac{y}{x}$, where $\frac{y}{x} \in R^+ \subset H$ and by assumption, $H \le R^*$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: Couldn't you just as easily assume that $H \neq R^*$ and then conclude $-1 \notin H$ and thus $H = R^+$?

Comment: That is equivalent logically, but I would have to think about the proof before I would agree with the "easily" adverb.

Comment: Maybe rephrase to "similarly"? Regardless, my issue is that it appears to me that we can assume $H \neq R^+$ and $H \neq R^*$ and validate/justify both.

Comment: Consider the set of cosets $\{x R^{+} : x\in R^{*}\} =\{R^+,R^-\}.$ In any group $G$ with subgroup $K$, if $\{x K: x\in G\}$ has exactly two members then any subgroup $H$ with $K\subset H\subset G\}$  satisfies $H\in \{G,K\}$

Comment: A common technique to proving statements of the form P or Q is to assume one is false and show that the other is true.